# MongoDB aggregate by ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have document like:

```
user: {
  _id: 5d8fa9881c9d4400006d13ab,
  connections[5e1ba6f12fc39330a3ebd1b0,...]
 }
```

and many another like:

```
connection: {
   authors: [5d8fa9881c9d4400006d13ab, 5d8fa9881c9d4400123213as] 
  _id: 5e1ba6f12fc39330a3ebd1b0
}
```

So each new connection Schema is pushed in User connections array. I want to aggregate user.connections to show all informations from each connection in that array

Comment: My sugestion is to just rethink your stracture. Mongo DB is a NoSql DB. And so, you shouldn't use it like a relational database. If you to it like this your gonna make too many queries for this single information and you will loose the best benefit of a NoSql db. I suggest that you just insert the connection object inside the user List.

Comment: I think this can help you https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: @Feronimus Yeah I thinked about that but every connection is shared between two users...the connection between them, what can you tell me more? thank you

Comment: @Feronimus Inside I plan to store chat messages and some other stuff that i don't want to duplicate, what do you think?

Comment: Well if your gonna use NoSql you will have faster queries but you will have dublicates. Read Further here please. https://www.quora.com/Is-it-ok-to-duplicate-data-in-a-NoSQL-database-I-would-appreciate-any-detailed-answer

Comment: @Feronimus So is it OK to have mesages and from publisher and from consumer in each user document, basically every message is duplicate? It will be a lot duplicated data